# Game Center vs OpenFeint

Tags: iphone, game-center, openfeint

I would like to add a global leaderboard for my games score.

Would you recommend Game Center or OpenFeint for implementing this?

What is needed to setup a global leaderboard? Is the server hosted by the service?

Thanks

Comment: didnt see this comment until now. Are you still struggling? http://pocketworx.com/?p=80 shows how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use both networks if you can!
I know many users, who prefer one of them and hate the other.

As far as I know has Openfeint built in GameCenter integration.
Giving the user the chance to use both gives you the best of both worlds.

Answer (score 1):

Game Center definitely.

It's officially supported by Apple so it's really well integrated into the sdk and there's no guarantee Apple will not prohibit all third-party game networks at some point in the future.

The servers are hosted by the service (for Game Center at least)

Comment: Thanks. I already implemented OpenFeint and it works really well. I dont think apple would prohibit OpenFeint with such a huge user base and already implemented games. Who knows. :P

Answer (score 1):

One important difference between the two is that OpenFeint has Android support. That is something to consider if you are multiplatform.